# Is it possible to play audio from a local ios library via html5?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile-safari, web-audio-api

Say we have an iPhone that has mp3s synced to it that play normally with the built in ios music player. Can a webpage be coded in a way that if I surf to it using mobile safari, I can see my music library and play the files? 
If so what APIs etc should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS, this is not possible.  It *is* possible for Chrome Applications to get access to the local media library; however, iOS (even Chrome on Android right now, actually) do not support this.

Answer (score 0):

As browser limitations and security concerns 
you cannot do this.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to say no.  I'm 99% certain there's no way to do that.  The only files you can access are the photos, and those are one-by-one using  .