# Cannot get WebAudio to play through iOS 8

Tags: javascript, ios, web-audio-api

I have been trying to get WebAudio working in Safari on iOS8 (i have succesfully got it working in Windows and on Android devices).

It is my understanding that you cannot automatically play webaudio through Safari on iOS, but instead you must trigger the first WebAudio call through a user action (e.g. a button press). Then once this first user-driven action is done, WebAudio will work.........Apparantly.

So i have a button set up (using JQM) like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="PlayDing('Silent');" data-icon="info" data-role="button" data-mini="false" data-theme="b" data-corners="false">Enable Audio</a><hr />
```

"PlayDing" is a function which looks like this:

```
function PlayDing(DingType) {
var sound = new Audio('../../UI/Audio/' + DingType + '.mp3').play();
}
```

The idea is that by clicking the "Enable Audio" button, this triggers a user interaction to play an mp3 file (which is just 1 second of silence) and then subsequent audio events will just work.

Any ideas why this is not working on iOS8 / Safari?

EDIT:

If i change my JQM button to play a proper ding sound, it works fine and my iPad plays the ding.

EDIT 2:

This is nothing to do with playing audio files from my iPad's music library. This is about playing files / resources that are part of the website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to play audio from a local ios library via html5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803399/is-it-possible-to-play-audio-from-a-local-ios-library-via-html5)

Comment: Um. No. This is not a duplicate. That question was around viewing their local media files. I'm on about playing an mp3 which is a resource in the website. Also, I have edited the question to include some more info.

Answer (score 2):

*"It is my understanding that you cannot automatically play webaudio through Safari on iOS, but instead you must trigger the first WebAudio call through a user action (e.g. a button press). Then once this first user-driven action is done, WebAudio will work.........Apparantly."*

You are completely right about the handling of the playing. To avoid playing unwanted sounds or unwanted download of sounds onto users devices possibly using up monthly data - a soundplay has to be called in the same stack as the user's touch/click.

There are multiple of things you have to deal with to make sure all your users can reliably play the sound. One thing is it has to be downloaded before you play it. To achieve this we use a technique called preloading.

You also have to take into account that not all users support the same audio format.

An example of your HTML and Javascript could be as follows:

**Javascript:**

```
function PlayDing(DingType) {
     //Get a reference to the audio element
     var sound = document.getElementById(DingType);
     //Play it
     sound.play();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
     <!--Declare the sounds in as many formats as possible and let the user's browser handling what sound to play & caching -->
     <audio id="Silent" preload="auto">
          <source src="'../../UI/Audio/silent.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
          <source src="'../../UI/Audio/silent.wav" type="audio/wav">
          <source src="'../../UI/Audio/silent.aac" type="audio/mpeg">
     </audio>

     <a href="#" onclick="PlayDing('Silent');" data-icon="info" data-role="button" data-mini="false" data-theme="b" data-corners="false">Enable Audio</a>
     <hr />
</body>
```